# Download financial transactions

Tags: transactions, financial

Is there a C# library or something I can use to download credit card/bank transactions to do processing like what Mint, MS Money, etc. does?

Comment: You mean an accounting API? A/P, A/R, journal entries, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe mint uses Yodlee http://www.yodlee.com/ -- they have an API